# securely strip html tags in javascript with whitelist

Tags: javascript, security, dom, xss

I want to strip almost every html tag from a string in javascript, allowing only a few  basic tags
(& strip their attributes) to prevent *Cross-Site-Scripting*.

A [lot of people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067107/javascript-replace-allowed-html-tags) say, it shouldn't be done with javascript, because clients might have javascript disabled, causing the filter to break. However my whole project depends on javascript, and *no client with disabled javascript will ever see the output, plus I am unable to do it server-side.*

(1) Am I right to assume in this case it might be done securely?

[bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince) recommends [to use the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392931/how-do-i-strip-all-html-tags-in-javascript-with-exceptions?answertab=votes#tab-top) (instead of RegEx) to filter the potentially insecure input. I am certainly no XSS expert but because his example depends on the string being inserted to the DOM **before** the filter does his job, I could imagine it might be insecure because of something like:

```
var unsecureString = '<img src=".." onload="alert(\'bad\')" />';
$('#alice').update(unsecureString);
filterNodes($('#alice'), {p:[],a:['href']}); // see link above
```

(2) Can I be certain, the bad event above won't ever fire?

(3) If not: How to avoid such problems, but still use the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at the google caja sanitizer.

https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/JsHtmlSanitizer

Comment: This!  Writing one's own is extremely challenging to get right.